# Concerned with Top in sql

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have variable @count of datatype int.I am setting values to this @count.
I want to select top @count number of rows from table. When i use `Select top @count`, its showing error.

```
  IF (@NewItemCount<@OldItemCount)
    BEGIN
        set @count=@OldItemCount-@NewItemCount
        if(@count>0)
        BEGIN
            Delete from ItemDetails where  GroupId in (Select Top @count  Id from ItemDetails where GroupId=@Prm_GroupId )
        END
    END
```

The error is

> Incorrect syntax near '@count'.

Comment: What are you trying to do here, it doesn't really make sense... At a basic level you need an @Count = Id in your sub statement, but not sure what that will do...

Comment: equally as lost - try to state what you're doing in simple terms without any code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to go down the dynamic SQL route I would recommend you read [this excellent article first](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Edit:

Wrapping the @count variable in brackets should work for you:

```
 IF (@NewItemCount<@OldItemCount)
BEGIN
    set @count=@OldItemCount-@NewItemCount
    if(@count>0)
    BEGIN
        Delete from ItemDetails where  GroupId in (Select Top(@count)  Id from ItemDetails where GroupId=@Prm_GroupId )
    END
END
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to use a variable in this spot.

One solution would be to use dynamic sql: build the complete querystring that you want to execute in a string-variable and have that executed.

Answer (score 2):

This works out of the box on SQL Server 2005 ***without*** any dynamic SQL.
You were just missing parenthesis. Following works like a charm:

```
DECLARE @CNT INT
SET @CNT = 5

SELECT  TOP (@CNT) *
FROM    MYTABLE
```

Comment: do you really have SQL Server 2005?